# How to verify the correctness of configuring mutual authentication (client certificate, server certificate) Java EE?

Tags: java, security, authentication

I am trying to write a simple application to understand the basics of configuring authentication based on client and server certificates.

I have done everything as it is explained in jave ee 5, java ee 6 tutorials
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glien.html

1. Opened example from javaee tutorials hello basicauthorization (just simple servlet which can be accessed only after authentication) and then reconfigured it for client certificates instead of basic authorizations
2. Configured web.xml
3. Configured glassfish-web.xml
4. Generated client certificate
5. Imported client certificate so that the server would trust it.

The problem:

When I deploy my application, and follow the link, corresponding to the application, I get a message from glassfish server HTTP Status 400 - No client certificate chain in this request".

So, it seems, that the client (browser) doesn't send the certificate with the request

I tried adding the .cer certificate to Chrome, firefox, internet explorer and they are added (no error is displayed), but as you see that doesn't help.

So, the question is:

How to get the access to my application through the web browser having client .cer certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug ssl on the server-side by adding (somewhere in Glassfish) system properties:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

see [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) for details.

You can also debug from the client perspective using openssl tool:

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port -debug -msg
```

you should see something like this:

```
...
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=PL/O=company/OU=xx/CN=host/emailAddress=email@example.com
/C=PL/O=company/OU=xx/CN=ca/emailAddress=email@example.com
---
SSL handshake has read 2536 bytes and written 116 bytes
...
```

your problem is probably related to bad truststore configuration on the server-side - server sends some *Acceptable client certificate CA names* (or no at all), but browser doesn't have anything to offer - it **doesn't have any private key+certificate issued by acceptable ca**.

Comment: So, the problem is that "browser doesn't have anything to offer - it doesn't have any private key+certificate issued by acceptable ca". How to make browser to use the certificate which I generated?

Comment: In IE you have option to choose *container* for certificate - you must choose "personal certificates" (something like this). Are you sure server is asking for your certificate?

Comment: Not sure. In order to make server trust my certificate I used this command: java-home\bin\keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias client-alias -file client.cer -keystore domain-dir/config/cacerts.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit as it is proposed here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glien.html

Comment: But the error doesn't say that the certificate is wrong. It says that the client doesn't send the certificate.

Comment: Tried adding the certificate using "personal certificates" in IE. No effect

Comment: have you tried connecting to Glassfish using openssl? You'll see what certificates (CA names) does Glassfish expect.